# Symfony centralize code

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to symfony 2.8. 
I do the same code pattern in each of my controllers to get the same data, put in different views, following this pattern:

```
 public function someMethod(Request $request){
    //1)  instanciate entity manager 
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    //2)   Fetch some datas ..
    $datas = $em->getRepository('MyCustomBundle:Entity')->findAll();
    $otherDatas = $em->getRepository('MyCustomBundle:AnotherEntity')->findAll();

   //3) Inject datas into view
   return $this->render('MyCustomBundle:Views:myview.html.twig', array('data'=>$datas,'otherDatas'=>$otherDatas));
   }
```

Is it possible to factorize all the getRepositories calls and arrays injection into a separated class ?

thanks for your help,

Comment: Sure.  Get familiar with dependency injection and services http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html.  Define your repositories as services and use $this->get('my.repository')->findAll().  Next, consider define your controllers as services so even the get can go away.  Lots of other things you can do as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is a Symfony-way. I would prefer 2.) and put your Code in the repository and just put some getters in the controller.

1. Make an abstract Controller class from which you inherit from.
2. I would do it with some redundant code. Put your repository getters in a method. Clean but redundant. If you have some complicated DB-Handling, put your code in the reposistory.
3. Build a service with your code and associate it in your Controller-Service. [Take a look here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/service.html)
4. Put your code in a trait.